# Override a portion of a file while recording AudioKit

Tags: swift, audiokit

I am using `AudioKit` in my project, where I have the main beat. I want to make it possible that user can start the recording from anywhere between the start and end duration of the beat and will override the old recoded file (only the portion user has chosen to record again), I have created an emply black audio file also. Is it possible to do so please help. Now every time it is making a new file ad started looping when all of them.